# Parser error with non-type in recursion

Tags: python, string, parsing

So a few days ago, SOCommunity helped me with a parser. ie this:

```
def MyList(self):
    class _MyList(list):
        def __init__(self, parent):
            self.parent = parent
            list.__init__(self)
    top = current = _MyList(None)
    ntab_old = 0
    for line in self.raw_data:
        ntab = line.count('\t')
        if(ntab_old > ntab):
            for _ in range(ntab_old-ntab):
                current = current.parent
        elif(ntab_old<ntab):
            current.append(_MyList(current))
            current = current[-1]
        current.append(line.strip('\t').strip('|'))
        ntab_old =ntab
    return top
```

Parsing through data like this:

```
 |[nothing detected] www.neopets.com/
        |status: (referer=http://www.google.com)saved 55189 bytes /fetch_d4cd213a56276ca726ddd437a1e75f1024ab7799
        |file: fetch_d4cd213a56276ca726ddd437a1e75f1024ab7799: 55189 bytes
        |file: decoding_367af53b4963986ecdeb9c09ce1a405b5b1ecd91: 68 bytes
        |[nothing detected] (script) images.neopets.com/js/common.js?v=6
            |status: (referer=http://www.google.com)saved 1523 bytes /fetch_8eeadcc08d4cb48c02dedf18648510b75190d1d7failure: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/tmp/tmpsha1_8d7fb3ff1ef087c7ea2bf044dee294735a76ed4b.js'
            |file: fetch_8eeadcc08d4cb48c02dedf18648510b75190d1d7: 1523 bytes
```

This is supposed to return nested lists containing each sub section. However, out of nowhere, I'm getting these errors:

```
      current.append(line.strip('\t').strip('|'))
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'append'
```

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: The data you posted above has an irregular mixture of tabs and spaces creating the indention. Is that the way your data really is?

Comment: Can you post the `repr` of your data snippet? That would show us exactly where the tabs are located.

Answer (score 2):

```
current.append(...)
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'append'
```

is saying that at some point `current` is `None`.

So how is `current` being set to `None`? My guess is it probably happens here:

```
        for _ in range(ntab_old-ntab):
            current = current.parent
```

If current is set to its parent often enough, it will eventually get set to `None` since at the top level, `_MyList` is instantiated with `None` as the parent:

```
top = current = _MyList(None)
```

---

This code might also be problematic:

```
    elif(ntab_old<ntab):
        current.append(_MyList(current))
        current = current[-1]
```

If `ntab` is say 3, and `ntab_old` is 1, then might need to move in two levels of "indention", but the code only creates one nested `_MyList`.

You might think that your levels of indention never jump by two. But that might be hard to tell with your eyes especially if the data is long. The data may not be as regular as we think.

Also, if there is a stray `'\t'` on the right-hand side of the `|`, then it would affect the `ntab` count even though it probably should not affect the indention level.

Comment: Oh, I see what you mean. But then, how would I prevent this from happening? :S I figured the only way you become a parent is if you have '0' tabs